# Java EE Enterprise JavaBeans Developer

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi

I intent to take the [Java EE 6 Enterprise JavaBeans Developer Certified Expert Exam](http://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=5001&get_params=p_exam_id:1Z0-895&p_org_id=&lang=) and am looking for an effective perparation way.

1) Based on the exam topics, could you recommend any books or any appropriate tutorials to study? As far as I am concerned there is no study guide.

2) I do not have any idea waht the exam questions look like. Are there any sample questions of this exam type on the Internet to look at, in order to gain an overview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to [these video tutorials](http://www.programming-simplified.com/index.html)

And try [EJB 3.1 Cookbook](http://www.packtpub.com/ejb-3-1-cookbook/book)

As well as [Enterprise JavaBeans 3.1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596158025)

And if you can spare some money take the Oracle online course "Develop Business Components with JMS & EJBs", you can find it on www.oracle.com

Good Luck studying

Answer (score 3):

Have passed the exam recently. All the above books are good but "Enterprise JavaBeans 3.1" by Rubinger and Burke is closer to exam's requirements. However none of these books and to my knowledge no other book will cover all exams requirements.
What you need also is enough familiarity with the specification and more specifically with:

1. JSR 318: Enterprise JavaBeansTM,Version 3.1EJB Core Contracts and Requirements
2. JSR 318 Interceptors 1.1 specification.

You must expect a lot of questions on the exam, from topics covered in the specs only (or with the required detail), like:

1. Deployment descriptor related, concerning security, session beans, transactions, interceptors etc.
2. Responsibilites of EJB Roles like "Bean Provider", "Application Assembler" , "Deployer" etc.
3. Exception Handling (In greater detail from Rubinger's coverage).
4. Application packaging (both war and ear).

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I personally read [EJB 3 in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988347) and it really covered all the topics connected with `EJB` and `JPA`, I learned a lot from it, so I can only recommend. However, you might want to read this [one](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596158033.do) because it also covers new stuff from `3.1` version (like Singletons for instance). And for the `CDI` and the rest - I think this [one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449370179) will be enough.

And for the second question, I suppose you can Google up some tests but I guess this certification is not going to be much difficult so better learn then cheat:-)